# About Hibernate save using Dynamic-Map entity mode

Tags: java, hibernate, hashmap

In the following example, how can I save the value of role to the role with id=1 without loading it? I have tried:

```
Map user = new HashMap<String,Object>();

user.put("address","Address test");
user.put("role",1);

session.save("User",user);
```

But that results in:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.hibernate.property.MapAccessor$MapGetter.get(MapAccessor.java:90)
```

And

```
Map user = new HashMap<String,Object>();

user.put("address","Address test");
user.put("role.id",1);

session.save("User",user);
```

Doesn't save the role, console shows this SQL:
Hibernate: insert into user (ts, address) values (?, ?)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the role should be a map

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, you need a `Session` working in map mode. I think something like this:

```
  SessionFactory sf = ...;
  Session s = sf.openSession();
  Session ds = s.getSession(EntityMode.MAP);
```

Then work with `ds` as you already attempted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<String,Object>();

user.put("address","Address test"); 

user.put("role", session.load("Role",1));

session.save("User",user);
```

This sentence:

```
session.load("Role",1)
```

doesn't make hibernate hit the database and the reference to the role with id=1 is successfully persisted in the new user.